# How to Populate the unbounded datagridview from SQL Server database in C#?

Tags: c#

In My Project I'm Using Unbounded datagridview with 33 columns for storing the user data in database and I need to populate the datagridview  after each and every Insert, Update and Delete.
My Problem is while populating the datagridview with sql server query it shows the column header repeated with data.

my code is given below :

```
Private Void PopulateGrid()
{
 cs.open();
 sqladpter da= new sqlcommand("Select * from Customer",cs);
 DataTable dt =new datatable();
 da.fill(dt);
 datagridview.datasource=dt;
 datagridview.Refresh();
}
```

I'll Call This method at the End Of each and every Insert, Update and Delete.

Answer (score 0):

How about Using something simple like datasource and you can have all your CRUD operations 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dz12d98w(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try setting `DataSource = null` before setting new DataSource

```
datagridview.DataSource = null;
datagridview.DataSource = dt;
```